# Why is my state not updating when called in useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

Have an annoying little bug in my application, which I am not sure is thanks to Redux states or something wrong with how I updated a internal state in React in a useEffect(). Either way I cannot seem to find an answer

I have a few `console.log()` throughout to try to better understand this.

I have a state in my App component,  `const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)` which determined where the page is loading, and if it is, returns a "loading" message on screen until all operations are completed. Inside my useEffect, depending on whether it is able to find a user in local storage, updates the state `loading` to `false` if there is a user found or if there isn't. When loading is false, the rest of applications routes are able to be rendered.

The issue I am having though, is that it seems as if my state does not initially update inside useEffect?

I do not have Strict mode because I am trying to see whats going on.

I have included a pic [image: picture] of my console logs, to give you an idea. As you can see after the useEffect is ran, even though it should updated `loading` state to `false`, upon rendering it has not updated, but somehow the `dispatch` inside useEffect has ran, because it shows the redux state has updated. Makes no sense to me.

After that, the App is loaded again, and somehow the loading state is not correct? Makes no sense to me

```
// React 
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

// Redux
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

// React Reducer
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { loginUser, logoutUser } from './reducers/user';

// Components
import Login from './components/Login';
import Player from './components/Player';

function App() {
  console.log("app start")

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
  console.log("user:",user)

  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)
  console.log("state:", loading)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in app effet")
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      console.log("inside json conditional")
      const user= JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      dispatch(loginUser(user))
      setLoading(false)
      return 
    } 
    setLoading(false)
  }, [])

  // If loading is false
  if (loading === false) {
    return (
      <div>
      {user && <h1><button onClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())}>LOG OUT</button></h1>}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={!user ? <Login/> : <h1>Home</h1>} />
        <Route path="/player/:username" element={<Player/>}/> 
        {user && <Route path ='/store' element={<h1>STORE</h1>}/>}
      </Routes>
    </div>
    )
  }
  console.log("end of app component")
// If Loading is true, not updated
      return (
        <h1>LOADING</h1>
      );
    }

export default App;
```

Comment: Even if I update the useState to false in setLoading before the dispatch is sent, the state still remains as true in the useEffect and the same logs happen

Comment: useEffect runs before render - I think when your `loading` is checked there, it's already false

Comment: also please mention what version of react you use - state updates being batched changed with 18

Comment: What is the code for `loginUser`? Is it an async function?

Comment: I am using the latest react, but strict mode is disabled so does not matter. As per loginuser, its just a reducer in the user slice, that sets the window.localStorage.setItem(action.payload), and returns the action.payload to update the state

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you may not get the correct value of loading just by console.log as batch process happens for the set state.

```
// React 
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

// Redux
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

// React Reducer
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { loginUser, logoutUser } from './reducers/user';

// Components
import Login from './components/Login';
import Player from './components/Player';

function App() {
  console.log("app start")

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const {user} = useSelector(state => state.user)
  console.log("user:",user)

  const [loading,setLoading] = useState(true)
  console.log("state:", loading)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in app effet")
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedUser')
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      console.log("inside json conditional")
      const user= JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON)
      dispatch(loginUser(user))
      //setLoading(false) 
    } 
    setLoading(false)
  }, [])

  // If loading is false
  if (!loading) {
    return (
      <div>
      {user && <h1><button onClick={() => dispatch(logoutUser())}>LOG OUT</button></h1>}
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={!user ? <Login/> : <h1>Home</h1>} />
        <Route path="/player/:username" element={<Player/>}/> 
        {user && <Route path ='/store' element={<h1>STORE</h1>}/>}
      </Routes>
    </div>
    )
  }
  else
    return <h1>LOADING</h1>
//   console.log("end of app component")
// If Loading is true, not updated
      
    }

export default App;
```

Comment: Comment, if any error. Will rectify it

Comment: No luck, because I also need to set setLoading to false even if no loggedUserJSON is found, to load everything else. And user cnanot be {user}

Comment: then do a single setloading outside if block. but is your UI updating accordingly?